# MVC sending a View based on the browser, not mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, cross-browser, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a single form that I had created for up to date browsers, but have to also ensure I have a version that renders fine on an embedded IE6 (old call center), I'm looking for a way to tell MVC to send my IE6 friendly form when it loads in that browser..
All the documentation I read is mobile related and has me confused.

Comment: Why do you need a different view for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC3, I believe you're limited to checking the user-agent string in the controller method, and returning the specific view you want to be returned.  Something like:

```
if(Request.UserAgent.Contains("MSIE 6.0"))
{
    return View("IE6View");
}
else
{
    return View();
}
```

Since you say you have a single form only, this might be the simplest direct solution.

If you're using MVC4, Display Modes is available, where convention is used to automatically select views based on conditions you outline in the Global.asax.  Decent write-up for this approach at the link below.  It's written for mobile-specific views, but could be easily applied to a different user-agent string condition.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975347.aspx